# How to find all appearances of text after a specific word?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-negation, regex-group

I get a string like:

```
str = “Test/hello/filename/12345678/first
Hddhkhd
Hdhal
filename/1212abcd/second”
```

I want to get an array of the all strings that comes after “filename//“ and I know that after the “/“ there is an 8 letter word that I want to get.

In this case, I want to get an array that will be:

```
strArr = [“12345678”, “1212abcd”]
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

A regex that captures the 8 characters that immediately follow a literal "filename//":

```js
/filename\/\/(.{8})/
```

Comment: You said "I know that after the “/“ there is an 8 letter word that I want to get." So, this captures 8 characters and ignores everything else. If the truth is that you want to select text based on different rules, you'll have to tell us what rules you desire. If you just want everything until the first space, you could do `/filename\/\/([^ ]+)/`.

Answer (score 1):

Try use this regex first:

```
filename\/\w{8}
```

and after it, slice from the result by this regex:

```
\w{8}$
```

First you will get:

> filename/12345678
>
> filename/1212abcd

Second you will get :

> 12345678
>
> 1212abcd

Comment: The regex will catch the string, just if it will be 8 characters. (That is what you wanted, no?)

Comment: @prasanth check my answer, I think it will work for string more than 8

Comment: @AmitDas. But he wanted exactly 8 characters.

Comment: @ut or, yes OP did mention 8 letter word, but I think that is too restricting. Your answer is absolutely fine given what OP asked. My guess is OP was just giving a specific example and not considering other test cases.

Comment: @AmitDas. So he can change the '8' to any number he want.

Comment: @ut or, he can but if he changes it to 9 then the regex will only work for 9 characters and no more. Similar in case of all other numbers. The regex will not allow any more characters than what is mentioned.

Comment: @AmitDas. So if he want he can concatenate some variable.

Answer (score 1):

You might also capture in a group matching 8 times not a forward slash or a newline after matching `/filename`

```
\bfilename\/([^\/\n]{8})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0QSNqn/1)

If you want to match 8 or more times you could use `{8,}` instead or if you want to match 1 or more times you could use a `+`.

If you don't want to match whitespace characters you could change the `\n` to `\s`

```js
const regex = /filename\/([^\/\n]{8})/g;
const str = `Test/hello/filename/12345678/first
Hddhkhd
Hdhal
filename/1212abcd/second`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For explanation check this [**REGEX**](https://regex101.com/r/kuFfxx/1)

```js
var arr = "Test/hello/filename/12345678/first Hddhkhd Hdhal filename/1212abcd/second".match(/(?<=filename\/)(.*?)(?=\/)/g);
console.log(arr)
```

OR

For unsupported Lookbehinds browser use `Array#map` after regex

```js
var arr = "Test/hello/filename/12345678/first Hddhkhd Hdhal filename/1212abcd/second".match(/filename\/(.*?)\//g).map(i=> i.split('/')[1]);
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. It will match all characters after the `filename/` until it encounters another `/`. After you get the matches in an array you can `map` it out and `replace` all the `filename/` with `''`:

```
let a = /filename\/[^\/]+/g;
let b = 'Test/hello/filename/12345678/first Hddhkhd Hdhal filename/1212abcd/second';
let c = b.match(a).map(x=>x.replace('filename/',''));
console.log(c);
```